No sound on Linux with Intel Raptor Lake audio controller (ThinkPad L14)
I have a fresh install of Arch Linux, with no sound. I'm using a ThinkPad L14.
lspci | grep -i audio 
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS (rev 01)

aplay -l (after sudo pacman -S alsa-utils):
aplay: device_list:279: no soundcards found...

wpctl status showed that my sound card wasn't being used (only the dummy one was).
I installed Arch with Pipewire instead of Pulseaudio, so figured maybe switching back to Pulseaudio might help:
sudo pacman -S pulseaudio pulseaudio-bluetooth

Though this installed successfully and removed the pipewire-pulse client (I answered yes to resolve the dependency issue), it didn't solve the problem. So, I restored Pipewire:
sudo pacman -R pulseaudio-bluetooth
sudo pacman -S pipewire pipewire-pulse

Hail Mary time! I also tried a reinstall of linux and linux-firmware:
sudo pacman -Syu linux linux-firmware

No improvement. Sound still not working.
sudo lspci -v -s 00:1f.3 output:
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device 50db
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 189, IOMMU group 14
        Memory at 601db90000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at 601da00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_avs, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

Oh, this is interesting:
        Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl

That seems strange. I was expecting something like snd_hda_intel.
What is SOF?

The output indicates that the audio device is using the sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl kernel driver instead of the traditional snd_hda_intel driver. This is expected behavior for newer Intel hardware, such as Raptor Lake, as it uses the Sound Open Firmware (SOF) framework for audio.
Solution for Arch Linux:
sudo pacman -S sof-firmware alsa-ucm-conf
reboot


Same problem on openSUSE Tumbleweed, aplay -l:
aplay: device_list:279: no soundcards found...

Solution for openSUSE Tumbleweed:
sudo zypper install sof-firmware alsa-ucm-conf
sudo reboot

